# Colimits of short exact sequences of C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, limits-and-colimits, short-exact-sequences

Assume I have an inductive system of short exact sequences of $C^{\ast}$-algebras (i.e., short exact sequences $0 \to A_n \to B_n \to C_n \to 0$ together with transformations from the $n$-th to the $(n+1)$-st short exact sequence so that all squares commute). If I form now the colimit of the $C^{\ast}$-algebras, is the resulting sequence $$0 \to \varinjlim A_n \to \varinjlim B_n \to \varinjlim C_n \to 0$$ still exact? Note that I do not want to assume here that the connecting maps in the colimits I form are injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My notation
$$
  i_n:A_n\to B_n,
  $$
$$
  p_n:B_n\to C_n,
  $$
$$
  i:\displaystyle \lim_\to A_n\to \displaystyle \lim_\to B_n,
  $$
$$
  p:\displaystyle \lim_\to B_n\to \displaystyle \lim_\to C_n,
  $$
$$
  \beta _n:B_n\to\displaystyle \lim_\to B_n.
  $$

I suppose the only contentious  point is to prove that $\text{Ker}(p) \subseteq  \text{Im}(i)$, so suppose that this fails.  For
each $\varepsilon >0$ we may then choose some $b\in  \displaystyle \lim_\to B_n$, such that

- $\|p(b)\|<\varepsilon $,
- $\text{dist}(b,\text{Im}(i)) > 1-\varepsilon $.

Since the union of the images of the $B_n$ is dense in $\displaystyle \lim_\to B_n$, we may assume that $b=\beta_n(b_n)$, for some $b_n\in B_n$.

Increasing $n$, if necessary, we may assume that moreover $\|p_n(b_n)\|<\varepsilon $.  But this is a contradiction since
$$
  \varepsilon >\|p_n(b_n)\| = \text{dist}(b_n,\text{Im}(i_n))\geq $$ $$ \geq\text{dist}(\beta _n(b_n),\text{Im}(i))=
  \text{dist}(b,\text{Im}(i)) >1-\varepsilon .
  $$

Comment: Looks good, thanks! I think that we need to use that images of ${}^*$-homomorphisms between $C^*$-algebras are closed, otherwise you might not be able to find the element $b$ in the first step. Actually, that the map $i$ is injective is also not completely trivial: I had to use that each of the maps $i_n$ is isometric since they are injective.

Comment: Alex, you are correct on both of your claims.  Indeed what makes life so much easier when dealing with $^*$-homomomorphisms on C*-algebras is that every such map is isometric when the kernel is modded out, so, as you say, must have a closed range.   I figure Banach space people must be very envious of us for this!